Typescript - Could Intersection type be considered as Subtype of the type that is contained in that intersection?
I have a question that relates to generic type and subtype concepts in Typescript. But after spending a while reading Typescript official document I still haven't found the answer. My question is that: Could Intersection type be considered as subtype of the type that create the intersection.
I have the following type:
type Dog = { color:string}
type Cat = { gender:boolean}
type Fish = { weigh: number}

type Dog_Cat_Fish = Dog & Cat & Fish;
type Dog_Cat = Dog & Cat;

Can I state that:

Dog_Cat_Fish  is subtype of Cat (1)
Dog_Cat_Fish  is subtype of Dog_Cat  (2)
T & U is subtype of T (3)
T & U & V is subtype of T & V (4)

Where T,V and U are *type variables ( generic types).
Thank you for considering my stupid question.

If you consider these to be set operations, an intersection always results in a set that is a subset of both of the original sets so (T & V) & U will be a subset of T&V and also a subset of U (and also T&U is a subset of T)

The answer to all 4 of your bullet points is yes.
This is the case even when the members of your types are incompatible
type Dog = { color:string }
type Cat = { color:boolean }
type Dog_Cat = Dog & Cat

No values of this type can exist, however it is a subtype of both Dog and Cat. It is equivalent to never, but might not be displayed as such by tools

this is the first time I see that, your example make me surprised
